# Find all 8 elements of order 3 in $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

What does the notation $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$ actually mean? Is it $(x_1,x_2)$?

Comment: It means pairs of real numbers, but only up to shifts by integers. For example, $(1.1, 5.6) = (0.1, 0.6) = (-0.9, 100.6)$.

Comment: ohhh okk thxxxx

Comment: ahh i got it now thx

Comment: Also, check out [the guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Comment: Additively or multiplicatively?